# Why do we have two ways to add an event listener on a view in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, event-handling

In android, we have two ways to add an onClick listener on a view, one is through the XML and the other is through the java code.
Why do both of them exist and why does android provide us two ways for that?

What good does it do to the overall code or is it due to the way the android framework works or is it due to the time taken to write a code or is there anything more to it?

Answer (score 0):

For explanation about defining `onClick` attribute in android in the `XML layout` vs `Java/Kotlin` code, since I wouldn't like to take any credits from this video, so I am linking the resource for you, it has almost every aspect for your question covered by this channel. Feel free to comment and ask me again if anything sounds confusing to you.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMVlhTT9fL4